# Logging Of 400 Error Mssage

Tags: apache, logging

In Production Environment,When I make Request for my web page.The Request show in apache's access logs,but not in configured my configured web logs.

My logback.xml is

```
 <configuration>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
<jmxConfigurator />
<property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN"
    value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p ${PID:- } --- [%15.15t{14}] %-40.40logger{0} : %m%n" />
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>/var/log/company_name/payments.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

And My controller is

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/my/v1")
public class PaymentApi {

@RequestMapping(value = RestURIConstants.VOID_TRANSACTION, 
                method = RequestMethod.POST )
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> voidPayment(@RequestParam("request") String voidRequestJson,
                                                   HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
  //Code here.
 }

    @ExceptionHandler
     void handleException(Exception e, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        logger.error("Error in Request : " + new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(e));
        if (e instanceof IllegalArgumentException) {
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), e.getMessage());
        return;
        }
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(), "an error occured while processing request");
    }

 }
```

I am making web Request using below code.

```
 public static <T extends Response,S extends Request> T doPostRequest(S request,
                                                              Class<T> responseClass,
                                                              String urlString) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    logger.info("Sending Request " + objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request));
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("request=" + objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request), headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = null ;

    response = restTemplate.exchange(urlString, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

    logger.info("Response recieved " + response.toString());
    if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK || 
            response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR) {
        return  objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody(), responseClass) ;
            //  gson.fromJson(response.getBody(), responseClass) ;
    }else{
        return  objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody(), responseClass) ;
    }
  }
```

Same code is working for my local ,But in production it throws 400 Error and also there are no logs in payments.log file.

The Java version in production on my payment server is on 1.8.0_25 and server which is making these request are on 1.8.0_91.

I am unable to identify the reasons as there are no logs are present for this web request in payments.log

Answer (score 0):

their is limit on header size on production.Because of that i am getting this issue and there are no logs in payments.log.